# How to Run flash applications in any browsers with out adding manual extensions in 2023

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex4

We have a flash based game applications which were developed in 2016 and we are working on running these games in browsers like (Chrome and Mozilla) but are observing swf file is not being executed and getting the pop up in browser for not supporting the flash.

What are the options we have to run flash application with out doing the code changes ..?